# Remove staged file and reset to original version

Tags: git, git-reset, git-stage

If I have a file in the staging area (showing in `git diff --cached`) and I want to remove it completely how do I do that?
Doing

```
git reset HEAD -- file  
git checkout -- file
```

does it but is there 1 command for these 2 actions?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove it"?

Comment: @Maroun:I mean that I want the original file in that branch untouched

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
git checkout HEAD -- file
```

does the trick.

#### Longer version with a lot of background

There are many (too many, sometimes) things to know about this.  First, the *index* (also known as the *staging area* or the *cache*) holds *all* files-to-be-committed at *all times*.  In fact, each file's presence *in* the index is what means the file will be committed, in the form it has in the index.  This is *why* you have to keep doing `git add file` all the time: Git won't copy it from the work-tree into the index, overwriting the *old* index version, until you tell Git to do so.

When you initially check out some commit, the index normally holds a copy of every file that's in that commit as well.  There are some exceptions (see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for details), but usually, the initial setup is:

```
  HEAD      index     work-tree
-------------------------------
README.md  README.md  README.md
file1.txt  file1.txt  file1.txt
```

and so on, with *all three versions of each file matching*.

There are some slight but important differences between each copy, though:

- The copy in the commit, in `HEAD`, is read-only. *Nothing* can change this copy.  (Of course, `HEAD` itself can change to be another, different, commit; the different commit can have a different copy of the file, or maybe not have the file at all.)  The committed copy of the file is in a special Git-only format.
- The copy in the index / staging-area is read/write.  This copy is also in the special Git-only format, though.  You can at any time copy a different version of that file into the index, or even remove the index entry.
- The copy in the work-tree is in your computer's normal format.  You can do anything you like with it, subject to whatever limits your computer imposes.

What `git status` does—well, one of the many things it does—is to run *two* comparisons:

- What's in `HEAD` vs what's in the index.  Whatever is *different*, Git lists as staged for commit.
- What's in the index vs what's in the work-tree.  Whatever is *different*, Git lists as not staged for commit.

This means you don't have to wade through huge lists of everything that's *the same*; you only see what's *different*.

#### `git add` = copy from work-tree to index

Using `git add path` copies the work-tree version into the index.  That's pretty simple!  Of course, Git being Git, there are more varieties of `git add`, but we will just ignore them for now. :-)

#### `git reset` = ... well, it's complicated

The `git reset` command does too many different things.  However, **if you stick with `git reset -- path`**, it simplifies a lot: it means *copy from the `HEAD` commit to the index*.  The work-tree copy remains untouched.

#### `git checkout` = copy from ... well, it's complicated too

The `git checkout` command, like `git reset`, does too many different things.  However, if you stick with these two forms, we get two things that are easy to explain:

- `git checkout -- path` copies from the index to the work-tree.
- `git checkout HEAD -- path` copies from the `HEAD` commit to the index, and then from the index to the work-tree.

There's one option missing here: there is no easy way to copy from `HEAD` commit to the work-tree, bypassing the index.  (There are a few ways to do this but they have certain caveats.)

You cannot write on the `HEAD` version, so there is no way to copy into `HEAD`.  Instead, you will run `git commit`, which makes a *new* commit, freezing the index copy (of every file!) forever.  The new commit then *becomes* the `HEAD` commit.  The fact that all the files are already in their final form in the index, when you run `git commit`, is part of what makes `git commit` so fast.

Comment: I have never seen this command before. I need to study your detailed answer!

Comment: When doing `git reset` the file is removed from the staging area but the changes are in my working tree. What do you mean by "untouched"? Also is the `--` needed in the `git checkout`?

Comment: By "untouched", I mean the command itself makes no changes to the work-tree copy of the file. You may or may not have made changes to the work-tree copy, but `git reset -- <path>` does not make changes to it. As for the `--`, this is required if and only if the Git command might think that the file name means something else. For instance, what if you have a file named `master`, or a file named `-f`? These look like branch names and command options. The `--` makes sure Git knows which arguments are which. It's a good habit to get into using `--` always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset filename.txt`

This will remove a file named filename.txt from the the staging area.

You can also use `git reset` to unstage all files.

Good luck!

Comment: That will keep it as a checkout file

Comment: I thought that's what you meant by "removing" the file from the staging area. In that case, I believe you will have to stick to using both commands.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a single file from the staging area, you can just use:

```
git reset HEAD -- <file>
```

To remove a whole directory or folder from the staging area, you can just use:

```
git reset HEAD -- <directoryName>
```

For newer versions of Git, You can also use: `git restore --staged <file>.`

Sometimes you may need to remove cache also: `git rm -r --cached .`